# SQL Server Profiler find stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have this code in visual basic calling a stored procedure:

```
cmdr.CommandText = "EXEC [DATABASE].[USER].[BOMBA]" & cd_ponto & ",NULL," & ds.Tables("pt_col1").Rows(0).Item("qtde_pt_consumo_med") & ",'" & hr & "'"
```

But I need to see the values/args that are being passed to the procedure. I'm trying to figure it out by using SQL Server Profiler, but it is not appearing.

What can I do?

Comment: That code looks like an injection nightmare. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: Not tried it but seems well explained here: https://jackworthen.com/2018/07/23/capturing-the-parameters-of-a-stored-procedure-call-using-sql-server-profiler/

Comment: As I'm using amazon's rds web edition, I cannot solve it using the article's solution :/ 
@Larnu Thank you for the observation, I will refactor it eventually

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger to see the values passed? Or just the resulting CommandText property?

Comment: What do you see in the profiler?

Comment: So what Event Classes do you have enabled (ticked) in the Trace Properties? Not all event classes include the `TextData` column that would show your `CommandText` above.

Comment: @DaleK I see the TextData like > WHERE COD_PONTO = "@COD_PONTO", as parameters without specifying the value.

Comment: I have all Stored Procedures and T-SQL event classes enabled @AlwaysLearning